# I think the answer to this question is wrong: Consider $s,t \in \Bbb Q$. Show: $s \leq t$ if and only if $s^* \subseteq t^*$

Tags: real-analysis

There is a question in the Elementary Analysis The Theory of Calculus book that goes something like this:

Consider $s,t \in \Bbb Q$.

**(a)** $s \leq t$ if and only if $s^* \subseteq t^*$

where $s^* = \{r \in \Bbb Q : r < s\}$ and $t^* = \{r \in \Bbb Q : r < t\}$ are Dedekind cuts in $\Bbb Q$.  The answer in the back of the book is this:

If $s \leq t$, then clearly $s^* \subseteq t^*$ . Conversely, assume $s^* \subseteq t^*$ but that $s > t$. Then $t \in s^*$ but $t \notin t^*$ , a contradiction.

Ok, that makes no sense to me, since we already know that $t$ is not an element of $t^*$.  $t^*$ contains all the elements in $\Bbb Q$ that is less than $t$.  So, I don't understand this answer.  Here is what I think the answer should be:

Conversely, assume $s^* \subseteq t^*$ but that $s > t$. Then $t \in s^*$.  However, since $s^* \subseteq t^*$, then $t \in s^*$ implies $t \in t^*$.  This is a contradiction, since $t^*$ contains elements strictly less than $t$.

Thoughts?

Comment: The first answer says that if $t \in s^*$ (which follows from the fact that $s > t$), implying that $t \in t^*$. *This* is a contradiction, and is essentially the exact same contradiction that you make in your last paragraph.

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction. Suppose $s^*\subseteq t^*$ and $s > t$. By definition since $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $t < s$, $t\in s^*$ (since $s^*$ contains all rationals less than or equal to $s$). However since $s^* \subseteq t^*$, we see that $t\in t^*$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, never mind.  I guess it was just the way it was worded.  I misread it.  The author is saying t∈s∗ but t is not supposed to be in t∗.  The answer was just condensed.